# click on li if no leaf node its append in another div

Tags: javascript

I have one Activity xml file and I am try to get from activity when click on activity there child display. Its look like end of the all click.

```
  <ul id="firstLevelChild">
<ul id="ul">
    <li id="4">Activities
        <ul class="ul">
            <li id="10066">Physical1
                <ul class="ul">
                    <li id="10067">Cricket
                        <ul class="ul">
                            <li id="10068">One Day</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Now I want that if li have no leaf node then its display in other another div. Something like:

Click on `Acitivities` there have child node `Physical1` and there also child `Cricket` and there chil `One Day` now one day have no child when click on `one day` its display in my `<div id="result"></div>`

Comment: Remark: [`li`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html) are only valid as direct childs of `ul`, `ol` or `menu`, your current HTML isn't valid.

Comment: @Zeta no matter i change my html format.

Answer (score 1):

I would add this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep. `ChildNodes()` isn't a function - since it looks like you're using jQuery, try [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think javascript could helpr you there. A part from the fact that you first build your DOM correct ;)

The hasChildNodes() method returns TRUE if the current element node has child nodes, and FALSE otherwise.

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_haschildnodes.asp

Comment: when i am try this `if($(".div li").ChildNodes().length > 0){` error is ChildNodes not a funtion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the markup you provided is how it's going to be always i.e. `ul` as child for all `li`. You just check if `ul` exists inside the current `li`. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/aqmQN/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <ul id="firstLevelChild">
       <li>
        <ul id="ul">
            <li id="4">Activities
                <ul class="ul">
                    <li id="10066">Physical1
                        <ul class="ul">
                            <li id="10067">Cricket
                                <ul class="ul">
                                    <li id="10068">One Day</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h2>Result</h2>

<ul id="result"></ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('#content li').each(function (i) {

    //for display purpose only
    $('#content').append('<span class="list">li(' + i + '):' + $('ul', $(this)).length + '</span>');

    //the code you needed
    if ($('ul', $(this)).length < 1) {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
          $('#result').append($(this).parent().html());
        });
    }
});
```